# perl: print a string from a hash that contains a reference to it

Tags: perl

Sorry if this is a bad title.

I have the following hash:

```
my %map = (
    'key1', 'hello',
    'key2', \'there'
);
print Dumper(\%map);
```

output:

```
$VAR1 = {
    'key2' => \'there',
    'key1' => 'hello'
};
```

I want to print out the value at `'key2'`. Here's what I've tried:

```
print "$map{key2}" => SCALAR(0x2398b08)
print "$$map{key2}" =>
print "$map->{key2}" =>
```

my goal:

```
print [some magic thing] => there
```

I'm new to perl, so I'm not 100% clear yet on how references behave and how to dereference them.  How do I get what I'm looking for?

Comment: And you can use `ref` to test whether it is a reference, and to what

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$map{key2}` is a reference to a scalar value `\'there'`, so you need to dereference it

Your `$$map{key2}` and `$map->{key2}` both treat `$map` as a *reference to a hash*, but it doesn't even exist so that is wrong

You must use braces to disambiguate the order of evaluation

```
${ $map{key2} }
```

is what you want. Or you can write it in two steps

```
my $val = $map{key2};
print $$val, "\n";
```

Comment: So in this context, the braces act like parentheses to indicate order of operations, correct? In other words, the double dollar `$$` IS the correct way to dereference a variable in general, but because it's a hash, the order is ambiguous so perl dereferenced the wrong thing.

Comment: @ewok: Well I shouldn't have used *ambiguous*. `$$map{key2}` is defined as `${$map}{key2}`, so it uses `$map` as a hash reference. The fact that that isn't what you want doesn't make it "wrong".

Answer (score 6):

`$map{key2}` returns the value of the desired element. The element is a reference to a string.<sup>[1]</sup> If you wish to print the string referenced by that reference, you need to dereference it.

```
say ${ $map{key2} };
```

References:

- [Mini-Tutorial: Dereferencing Syntax](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=977408)
- [References quick reference](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=69927)
- [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)
- [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)
- [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)
- [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html)

---

1. I doubt this is intentional! This surely indicates an error somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

I like to add the following line to all my perl scripts:
`use strict;`
This will keep you out of trouble with the scope of your variables.  It does require you to scope all your variables with at a minimum of "my".

The following will let you print the value (of the hash associated with "key2") directly,
without the intermediate step of copying it out to another variable first.

`print ${$map{'key2'}}, "\n";`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for helping. Did you test your answer? I think you might have missed the point that the value for "key2" is  a reference. Your code works for "key1" but needs another twist for "key2".

Comment: Good catch, I found where my test code was incorrect.  I had the following in my %map definition:

`'key2', '\'there'`

I fixed that and updated my answer appropriately!